# How do i store data from my program and be able to reaccess and see/edit it when i reopen it? Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm fairly new to programming, at first i thought mysql would do the job then i realized that there must be another way. What i want to do is, in the next program, whenever i input a name i want to be able to store all of them, and be able to print them all on a list later on, also be able to edit them... What tools, instructions, should i use for this?

```
def contactsav():
    global whatname
    print "" \
          "" \
          ""
    print whatname, "Saved"

def regc():
    global whatname
    whatname = raw_input("Please introduce your clients first and last name.")
    contactsav()

whatname= ''
ans = True
while ans:
    option = input("""
        Hi, what do you wish to do
        1. Register a client.
        2. Check when the next maintenance is due.
        """)
    if option == 1:
        regc()
```

I'm going to make a simple gui for this, with buttons, entries, and labels.

Comment: See [Data Persistence and Exchange](http://pymotw.com/2/articles/data_persistence.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got it correctly, but you can try to, instead of saving the name to the string "whatname", append it to a list.

```
whatname = ""
list_of_names = []

def regc():
    global whatname
    whatname = raw_input("Please introduce your clients first and last name.")
    list_of_names.append(whatname)
    contactsav()
```

They will all be stored in list_of_names.
However, if you close the program, and re-run it, you will lose everything as it is only saved temporarily in memory.
If you want to be able to store and retrieve at any time the saved names, you have to use a database, such as MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: That's perfect, i made improvements now, but i still wish to know how to keep data when i close the program, i want to make a gui and package it and be able to install it, run it, gui opens, open and close it whenever i want and just deal with the gui from then on.